# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare spl_autoload_register()

Tags: php, autoload

```
<?php

function spl_autoload_register($class){require_once"{$class}.class.php";}

class ConDB
{
    private static $cnx;
    private function setConn()
    {
        return
        is_null(self::$cnx)?
            self::$cnx=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***","***","***"):
        self::$cnx;
    }
        public function getConn()
    {return $this->setConn();}
}
$cnx=new ConDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque simplesmente você esta tentando criar/redeclarar uma função com o nome da uma **função nativa existente**:

```
function spl_autoload_register($class){require_once"{$class}.class.php";}
```

Se a intenção é usar `spl_autoload_register`, o correto seria fazer isto:

```
function meu_autoloader($class) {
    require_once"{$class}.class.php";
}

spl_autoload_register('meu_autoloader');
```

Ou usar closure (função anonima do PHP) diretamente:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once"{$class}.class.php";
});
```